# How to let user set password on registration

Tags: users, front-end, user-registration, password

I´m working on a front end registration form adn have gotten as far as getting the standard registration form to work, but... I´d like to add the oportunity to let the user choose his/her own password.

I´m a bit noob at this so could anyone plese help me? :)

Here is my code so far:

```
<?php if(!is_user_logged_in()) { ?>


<?php
if(get_option('users_can_register')) {
//Check whether user registration is enabled by the administrator
?>

<?php

if($_POST){
    //We shall SQL escape all inputs
    $username = $wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['username']);
    if(empty($username)) {
        echo "<span style='color:#FF0000'><strong>Error..</strong></span><br /><br />You have to fill in the username.";
        exit();
    }
    $email = $wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['email']);
    if(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/", $email)) {
        echo "<span style='color:#FF0000'><strong>Error..</strong></span><br /><br />please use a calid e-mailadress.";
        exit();
    }

    $random_password = wp_generate_password( 12, false );
    $status = wp_create_user( $username, $random_password, $email );
    if ( is_wp_error($status) )
        echo "<span style='color:#FF0000'><strong>Feil..</strong></span><br /><br />Username allready exist. please try another one.";
    else {
        $from = get_option('admin_email');
        $headers = 'From: '.$from . "\r\n";
        $subject = "Registration ok!";
        $msg = "Welcome, you are now registered. Here is your username and password.\Info:\Username: $username\Password: $random_password";
        wp_mail( $email, $subject, $msg, $headers );
        echo "<strong>You are now registered. An e-mail is now sent to you with your username and password..";
    }

    exit();

}
 else
{
//Embed the register form and javascript here

?>


<div id="result"></div>
<div style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:10px;">Fill in your info to register.</div>

<form id="wp_signup_form" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" style="width:250px; margin-bottom:3px;" placeholder="Username"><br />
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" style="width:250px; margin-bottom:3px;"><br />
<input type="submit" id="submitbtn" name="submit" value="Register" class="knapp" style="padding:8px;">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">                         
$("#submitbtn").click(function() {
$('#result').html('<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/loader.gif" class="loader" />').fadeIn();
var input_data = $('#wp_signup_form').serialize();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url:  "<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>",
data: input_data,
success: function(msg){
$('.loader').remove();
$('
<div>').html(msg).appendTo('div#result').hide().fadeIn('slow');
}
});
return false;

});
</script>
<?php
// embedded

}
?>

<?php
    }

else 
?>

<!-- regskjema end -->
<br />
Allready registered? Login to your account with the form in the sidebar.
<?php } else { ?>
You are allready logged in...
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its  Not has hard as you think it is :)

Add the password fields to your form :

```
password: <input type="password" name="pass1" style="width:250px; margin-bottom:3px;"><br />
repeat password: <input type="password" name="pass2" style="width:250px; margin-bottom:3px;"><br />
```

then in your `if($_POST){` replace this line:

```
$random_password = wp_generate_password( 12, false );
```

with this:

```
$pass1 = $wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['pass1']);
$pass2 = $wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['pass2']);
if ($pass1 != $pass2){
    echo "<span style='color:#FF0000'><strong>Error..</strong></span><br /><br />please use a passwords don't match.";
        exit();

}
$random_password = $pass1;
```

Comment: works like a charm!

Comment: It also worked for me, so +1.

Comment: Which file is this?

Comment: Also, any idea whether these changes would be lost once we upgrade wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can use internal WordPress function for check email field.
check this link [is_email](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_email)

```
$email = $wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['email']);
if( !is_email($email) ) {
    echo "<span style='color:#FF0000'><strong>Error..</strong></span><br /><br />please use a calid e-mailadress.";
    exit();
}
```

Posted as answer due to few reputation.